# Can I use a jsonpath predicate in a filter?

Tags: django, postgresql, json-path-expression

I have a model with a JSONField and need to select just the objects that have a certain value **somewhere nested** in the jsonb.

From the Django documentation I understand you can use `contains` but the Postgres `@>` operator for containment does not recurse into the structure.
I'd like to use `@? '$.** ? (@.mykey == "myValue")'` to filter. `myKey` and `myValue` are literals in my code, they are not user input.

Comment: So, what happened?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can always drop down to writing raw SQL.

```py
raw_queryset = MyModel.objects.raw("""
    SELECT * FROM myapp_mymodel
    WHERE jsonfield_name @? '$.** ? (@.mykey == "myValue")'
""")
```

But there are a bunch of [caveats](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/sql/) to using these.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the `@?` operator functions identically to the `jsonb_path_exists` function (see [this table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE)), which can be used directly in Django like so:

```py
from django.db.models import BooleanField, Func, JSONField
from django.db.models import Value as V

from myapp.models import MyModel

class JSONBPathExists(Func):
    """A Django QuerySet Function expression for PostgreSQL's `jsonb_path_exists`."""
    function = "jsonb_path_exists"
    output_field = BooleanField()

# assuming `MyModel.json_field` is a JSONField()
queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(JSONBPathExists("json_field", V('$.** ? (@.mykey == "myValue")')))
```

`Func` classes like this are possible for all of PostgreSQL's `jsonb_path_*` functions, needing only the appropriate `function` and `output_field`.

And for a solution to a question you never asked,

```py
# if `myValue` didn't happen to be constant, `jsonb_path_exists` and 
# friends allow passing an object mapping jsonpath variables to values
user_value = get_value_from_user()  # for example, 'myValue'
# we have to specify `output_field=JSONField()` so Django knows how to prepare 
# this value for the database
variables = V({"somevalue": user_value}, output_field=JSONField())
queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(
    JSONBPathExists("json_field", V('$.** ? (@.myKey == $somevalue)'), variables)
)

# if `myKey` is a variable, it gets more complicated, but is still possible
user_key = get_key_from_user()  # for example, 'myKey'
variables = V({"somekey": user_key, "somevalue": user_value}, output_field=JSONField())

# we can use `.keyvalue()` to break objects like 
# `{"myKey": "myValue", "otherkey": "othervalue"}`
# into arrays of key/value pairs like 
# `[{"key": "myKey", "value": "myValue"}, {"key": "otherkey", "value": "othervalue"}]`
# but it breaks when applied to non-objects, so we chain together two filters 
# to typecheck each item
queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(
    JSONBPathExists(
        "json_field", 
        V('$.** ? (@.type() == "object").keyvalue() ? (@.key == $key && @.value == $value)'),
        variables
    )
)
```